# FB.ui method 'permissions.request' deprecated? the response always be false for me

Tags: fb.ui

Here is my code:

```
    FB.ui({method: "permissions.request", "perms": 'publish_stream', 'display': 'popup'}, function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      console.log(response.perms)
    }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

And the result is always 'false', does anyone know the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `permissions.request` dialog is not (no longer?) in the spec for `FB.ui`:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

It seems that the only way to ensure that a user is logged in *and* has the required permissions for an action is to use a combination of `FB.login()` with the proper permission scope, and then `FB.api('/me/permissions')` to query the Graph:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
      if (response.data && response.data[0] && response.data[0].publish_actions) {
        console.log("You got'em!");
      }
    });
  }
}, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
```

Comment: `FB.login` will always trigger the popup/in page dialog – to just check the status, `FB.getLoginStatus` is the better choice.

Comment: @CBroe: In the use case where you simply want to check for login status, you are absolutely right. The advantage of `FB.login()`, however, is that you can specify a permission scope, which will be prompted in the dialog if necessary (pretty much like `permissions.request` used to do).